# MySQL returning same data different rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to get data from reviews table then, join the same table again but find different data (likes) based on the id of the first table (reviews) and find the corresponding description from yet another joined table (descriptions).

I know this might be hard to visualize but maybe someone will know why the likes from the second reviews table return the same data for different rows:

```
SELECT r.title, co.likes, d.description
FROM reviews r
INNER JOIN reviews co
INNER JOIN reviews_descriptions d
ON co.id = d.review_id
WHERE co.parent = 52
AND r.id = 52;
```

The result is two rows in which title and likes have the same data while the description field grabs different data (the correct way). Likes should have different data for each row.

Help please.

Comment: You missed adding the `on` part in the join.

Comment: I know, it's just I don't think I need it because I compare the second reviews table to the description table later on.

Comment: Looks like your table could use some tweaking if you have to use an inner join to get data related to the same ID.  Why can't you use r.likes instead of co.likes?

Comment: I am joining the same table because I need to select another field and make different calculations on it. I select all data relating to this certain id, for example and then I need another type of data from another id in the same table. Each id has different calculations on them.

Comment: That is my whole point.  Why do you need to join the table if you are joining on the same ID?  I don't think you are fully understanding what you are trying to accomplish.  What does likes contain?  A count?  What is parent compared to id?  Why are likes, parent, and id stored in the same table versus a one to many relationship?

Comment: I'm assuming by `co` these are comments on the review.  So you should have a separate comments table with parent referencing id as a foreign key to reviews.  You shouldn't store reviews and comments in the same table.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative for writing this and I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT r.title, co.likes, d.description
FROM reviews r, reviews co, review_descriptions d
WHERE co.parent = r.id AND d.review_id = co.id AND r.id = 52;
```

Since you are matching co.parent to 52 and r.id to 52, then you should have a join on co.parent = r.id, however, you should rarely have to do a join on the same table.  I think your tables are poorly formatted or you don't need to do the join in the first place and should be able to use r.likes instead of co.likes.

Comment: Devon the comments and reviews are basically the same thing that is why they are in the same table and are only differentiated by knowing if they are the parent (review) or child (comment). Basically I am trying to get the review data from reviews table and the description of the review, which is in another table, based on the comment (same table as review) which has the most 'likes'. All in one query. So the comment gotten is the one belonging to that comment with the most likes.

Comment: I understand that, but it breaks standards in database management.  You should really have them separated and linked by a foreign key.  The SQL I provided should still work based on how you presented the information above.

Comment: You are most likely more knowledgeable than me in this topic but, it seems absurd to me to have two tables with VERY similar structures except for one field which can actually be used, when everything can be in one table and have them represented by connecting information.

Comment: You should organize a table by what it contains.  Therefore you should have a reviews and comments.  You don't necessarily need a separate table for description but you could do header/description table for each.  You should be able to view the structure of the database with its relationships and know exactly what is where.

Comment: Interesting, it would certainly be beneficial and less troublesome, but, do you think it's possible to do what I am trying to do? I just came up with another simpler query and its returning an empty set.

Comment: BTW someone down-voted your answer and you don't deserve that because you've stuck around so I voted it up.

Comment: The query you provided causes the same problem, the likes fields have the same data instead of different values depending on the review/comment they belong to.

Comment: It shouldn't.  The `co.likes` is dependent on `co.parent = r.id`.  So there must be a different issue.  Is d.description loading correctly?

Comment: What does `SELECT id,likes FROM reviews WHERE parent = 52` return?  I'm assuming the values aren't properly loaded in the DB.

Comment: The descriptions shows all possible values as it should but the likes show the same number for each which is 3, and it should show 3 and 5.

Comment: SELECT id,likes FROM reviews WHERE parent = 52 returns: id - 54,55 and likes - 3,5

Comment: What happens when you get rid of the reviews r altogether?  `SELECT co.likes, d.description
FROM reviews co, review_descriptions d
WHERE co.parent = 52 AND d.review_id = co.id;`  I'm kind of surprised yours and mine didn't work after reviewing them both.  They should only be grabbing parent of 52 for co.likes.

Comment: Same thing, likes still have the same data and descriptions have the correct data, crazy right?

Comment: Yes, something about that doesn't make sense.  I'd probably need to see a DB dump or something to go any further.  Are you testing against the SQL directly or through a php script?

Comment: I am using the console on MySQL so yes, directly.